# TensorFlow v1: Got a high cost while doing the logistic regression

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using the tensorflow for a simple 3-layer logistic regression test, I got a very high cost(around 550) and 100% training accuracy through the program, but using the same dataset and use common neural network will give a cost at around 0.3 and 94% training accuracy. Both program are using "RELU->RELU->Sigmoid->cross_entropy cost" sequence, learning_rate=0.003, num_epochs=30000 and no mini-batch (by setting the minibatch_size=dataset's size), I checked again and again but have no idea on why the tensorflow version of program get such a higher cost and the 100% training accuracy is also doubtful. Can anyone help to advise what's the problem of this. Thanks in advance.
My code is here, the dataset link is on the [OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgJEwa-_w3Q0eCuJO1Ts4tPqHp4?e=crWioQ)

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
import scipy.io
import math
import numpy as np

tf.disable_eager_execution()


data = scipy.io.loadmat('datasets/data.mat')
# train_X.shape(2,211)
# train_Y.shape(1,211)
train_X = data['X'].T
train_Y = data['y'].T
print(train_X.shape)
print(train_Y.shape)

layer_dims = [train_X.shape[0], 20, 3, 1]


def create_placeholders(n_x, n_y):
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[n_x, None], name="X")
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[n_y, None], name="Y")

    return X, Y


def print_parameters(parameters):
    L = int(len(parameters) / 2)            # number of layers in the network

    print("The layer structure is " + str(L))
    print("The parameters contains " + str(parameters.keys()))
    for l in range(1, L + 1):
        print('W' + str(l) + " shape = " + str(parameters['W' + str(l)].shape))
        print('b' + str(l) + " shape = " + str(parameters['b' + str(l)].shape))


def initialize_parameters(layer_dims):
    tf.set_random_seed(1)
    L = len(layer_dims)
    parameters = {}
    for l in range(1, L):
        wl = 'W' + str(l)
        bl = 'b' + str(l)
        parameters[wl] = tf.get_variable(
            wl, [layer_dims[l], layer_dims[l - 1]], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1, seed=1))
        parameters[bl] = tf.get_variable(
            bl, [layer_dims[l], 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    print_parameters(parameters)

    return parameters


def forward_propagation(X, parameters):
    # RELU->RELU->...->RELU->Sigmoid
    A = X
    L = len(parameters) // 2
    for l in range(1, L):
        A_prev = A
        wl = 'W' + str(l)
        bl = 'b' + str(l)
        Z = tf.add(
            tf.matmul(parameters[wl], A_prev), parameters[bl])
        A = tf.nn.relu(Z)

    WL = 'W' + str(L)
    bL = 'b' + str(L)
    ZL = tf.add(tf.matmul(parameters[WL], A), parameters[bL])
    AL = tf.nn.sigmoid(ZL)

    return AL


def compute_cost(AL, Y):
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
        logits=AL, labels=Y))

    return cost

def random_mini_batches(X, Y, mini_batch_size=64, seed=0):
    m = X.shape[1]                  # number of training examples
    mini_batches = []
    np.random.seed(seed)

    permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
    shuffled_X = X[:, permutation]
    shuffled_Y = Y[:, permutation].reshape((Y.shape[0], m))

    num_complete_minibatches = math.floor(m / mini_batch_size)
    for k in range(0, num_complete_minibatches):
        mini_batch_X = shuffled_X[:, k * mini_batch_size: k *
                                  mini_batch_size + mini_batch_size]
        mini_batch_Y = shuffled_Y[:, k * mini_batch_size: k *
                                  mini_batch_size + mini_batch_size]
        mini_batch = (mini_batch_X, mini_batch_Y)
        mini_batches.append(mini_batch)

    # Handling the end case (last mini-batch < mini_batch_size)
    if m % mini_batch_size != 0:
        mini_batch_X = shuffled_X[:,
                                  num_complete_minibatches * mini_batch_size: m]
        mini_batch_Y = shuffled_Y[:,
                                  num_complete_minibatches * mini_batch_size: m]
        mini_batch = (mini_batch_X, mini_batch_Y)
        mini_batches.append(mini_batch)

    return mini_batches

def model(X_train, Y_train, learning_rate=0.003,
          num_epochs=30000, minibatch_size=211, print_cost=True):
    ops.reset_default_graph()
    tf.set_random_seed(1)
    seed = 3                                          # to keep consistent results
    # (n_x: input size, m : number of examples in the train set)
    (n_x, m) = X_train.shape
    n_y = Y_train.shape[0]                            # n_y : output size
    costs = []                                        # To keep track of the cost

    X, Y = create_placeholders(n_x, n_y)

    parameters = initialize_parameters(layer_dims)

    AL = forward_propagation(X, parameters)

    cost = compute_cost(AL, Y)

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
        learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        sess.run(init)
        print(sess.run(parameters["W1"]))
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):

            epoch_cost = 0.
            num_minibatches = int(m / minibatch_size)
            seed = seed + 1
            minibatches = random_mini_batches(
                X_train, Y_train, minibatch_size, seed)

            for minibatch in minibatches:
                (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) = minibatch
                _, minibatch_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={
                                             X: minibatch_X, Y: minibatch_Y})

                epoch_cost += minibatch_cost / num_minibatches

            if print_cost == True and epoch % 1000 == 0:
                print("Cost after epoch %i: %f" % (epoch, epoch_cost))
            if print_cost == True and epoch % 5 == 0:
                costs.append(epoch_cost)

        parameters = sess.run(parameters)
        print("Parameters have been trained!")

        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(AL), tf.argmax(Y))

        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

        print("Train Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: X_train, Y: Y_train}))

        return parameters


parameters = model(train_X, train_Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after two days research, I found the issue, this is caused by inproper cost function, I tried tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits as the cost function to do the binanry classification, that caused the very high cost. after changed that into tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits then the cost reduced to 0.2 which is much lower, and to 100% training accuracy, I find another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187801/tensorflow-neural-network-accuracy-always-100-on-train-and-test-sets?rq=1) indicated the issue, so after I changed "correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(AL), tf.argmax(Y))" into "correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.round(AL), Y)" then it's fixed.